# Python API EOFError

Tags: python-2.7, evernote, pythonista

I've some Pythonista scripts I run on my iPad which create/update Evernote notes as part of the process, at least they did up until around 20th/21st of December at which point they started throwing EOFErrors when trying to retrieve the note store (get_note_store). The following is enough to duplicate the error

```
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
import evernote.edam.notestore.NoteStore as NoteStore

auth_token = "……" # << add a valid token here
client = EvernoteClient(token=auth_token, sandbox=False)
note_store = client.get_note_store()
```

I did some playing around over the holidays and tracked the error down to something specific to Pythonista as the same code works flawlessly on my Mac, but as there hasn't been any updates to Pythonista since June 2016 (I'm still using the original version not Pythonista 3) I don't think the issue is on the Pythonista side.

Checking on the Evernote status page (http://status.evernote.com/) there were patch releases on the 20th and 21st of December and I'm wondering if one of these could have broken support for the Pythonista Evernote API?

**Update 2017-01-09**

It looks like a patch was applied to the Evernote servers Thursday night which has fixed the issue and everything is working ok again now.

If you happen to be part of the Evernote support team who had any involvement in fixing this, Thank you!

Regards,

Richard

Comment: We are not tech support from Evernote, so you'll have to contact them for the contents of the patches and what changed with them.

Comment: I was posting something similar... to be fair to the asker, Evernote's "API Discussion" subforum actually redirects to the Evernote tag page on SO. (Not that that's a good thing, or that it makes this any more Evernote's tech support.)

Comment: What's the version of the SDK are you using? If it's not the latest, is it possible to upgrade and see if that works?

Comment: I should have included the SDK version in my original post. I'm using 1.25 which I believe is the current version according to the Evernote GitHub https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python